# Not detecting TensorFlow GPU (TF_GPU - V1.15)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

am trying to run a Keras code. Everything works fine. Except i was wondering why was the training was taking so much time. Until i learnt that, the gpu is not getting detected. I tried to test if the GPU is being detected or not by this simple code below,
the error showed by red box in the image is on top of the picture. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.
One more thing, i installed tensorflow V1.15 as some of the modules are depricated in V2, so i had to downgrade it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfoRM.jpg

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()

True

>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)

2020-02-23 19:18:48.893786: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-02-23 19:18:48.911886: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-02-23 19:18:49.717223: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.62
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-02-23 19:18:49.722976: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
2020-02-23 19:18:49.728562: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_100.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_100.dll not found
2020-02-23 19:18:49.734177: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_100.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_100.dll not found
2020-02-23 19:18:49.740876: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_100.dll'; dlerror: curand64_100.dll not found
2020-02-23 19:18:49.748607: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_100.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_100.dll not found
2020-02-23 19:18:49.756587: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_100.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_100.dll not found
2020-02-23 19:18:49.862997: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-02-23 19:18:49.869116: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1641] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-02-23 19:18:50.439029: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-23 19:18:50.444445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0
2020-02-23 19:18:50.447461: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's working now when i upgraded it to v2. And all the deprecated codes i could reuse them with **tf.v1.compat**. 
For example, tf.get_session was depricated. Now i can use it in V2 by writing,
**tf.v1.compat.get_session** and it works.